# Android emulator not running on xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-emulator

> 1>Starting deploy VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone ...
>
> 1>Starting emulator VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone ...
>
> 1>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512
>   -no-boot- anim -avd VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone -propmonodroid.avdname=VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone
>
> 1>emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
>
> 1>emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
>
> 1>emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
>
> 1>emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error
>
> 1>emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error
>
> 1>emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version,
>   skipping check (current version '25.2.5-3567187')
>
> 1>Emulator VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone is running.
>
> 1>Waiting for emulator to be ready...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>...
>
> 1>Emulator is not ready to be used.
>
> 1>Deploy failed on VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone
>
> ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I am getting these errors while running emulator on xamarin. Please help me. My emulator is not running...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1 :** Download Intel [HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)

**Step 2 :** In the Windows search box, enter Programs and then click the Programs and Features search result, In the Control Panel Programs and Features dialog, click Turn Windows features on or off

**Step 3 :** Create x86 based emulator,

If you are developing 64-bit apps, install the following system images instead:

1. Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image
2. Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image

else download

1. Intel x86 Atom System Image
2. Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image

To install the necessary system images, start the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager) and scroll to the API level(s) you want to support. For each API level, enable the check mark next to the following system images:

And done,Now its will work.

[For More Detail follow this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/#sysimg)

Comment: My PC is AMD based...! Would that matter..?

Answer (score 0):

If you were like me and had virtualization on your system already and still getting this issue, the only way I fixed it was deleting the old emulator and just downloading the same one and relaunching/building the app.